# Skype iPhone app URL scheme

Tags: ios, iphone, skype

I've been using the skype:username?call URL scheme to launch the Skype app directly into a call, and was about to implement the skype:username?chat URL scheme to launch it directoy into chat... although the chat scheme is not working at all on the iPhone, and other tests seem to indicate that the call scheme is currently the only one that actually does work out of the many others I've seen documentation for.  I conducted a test a few weeks ago and could have sworn that the chat scheme WAS working, then I upgraded to their new app release and it's gone.

Was I just seeing things and it was never there?  Or did it really just disappear in this latest release?  I posted this to the Skype forums, which has still not recieved a single reply, and barely even any views, for over a week now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft states in their [Skype URI tutorial for iOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn745885(v=office.15).aspx):

> With the recent redesign of the Skype for iOS client, URIs are not
>   currently supported on the Skype for iOS 5.x branch.

Unfortunately, the Skype app still registers the `skype:` URL scheme (but doesn't actually do anything except launching the app) so we can't even check if the problem has been resolved.

Comment: can we open chat box in Skype of that user instead of calling

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried it on a few devices and with different versions of the iOS Skype software?

It seems as though that should be working. I use [handleopenurl](http://handleopenurl.com/) often for looking up app specific url schemes and they seem to have the chat url you listed [under their listing for skype](http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/skype).

Comment: Wish I could have. The day after the update on my phone I rushed to my iPhone carrying coworkers hoping they hadn't updated yet, but they all already had.  Even if I had an old version to test with, doesn't matter really if the new version isn't working.  I'm not gonna release a new version of my app with a new chat button that does nothing for the majority of the users (assuming most users update their apps everytime a new version comes out), until Skype releases a fix.

Comment: New version of Skype for iPhone and iPad came out recently, still no sign of the chat argument.

Comment: Another new Skype update today, still no sign of anything other than the call argument:(